# Using Mule Expressions in a Spring Configuration

Tags: spring, mule

I'm setting up a Mule application and in it, I wanted to use Spring beans to wire up an EHCache and JDBC connection. Instead of putting the configuration information in each Mule application I create, I wanted to use a properties file which would be located at $mule_home/conf.

I know how to use a Mule expression to access the Mule home directory(`#[mule:context.homeDir]`) but when I attempt to put that expression inside my context.xml file, which I link in my mule application configuration, and start up the server, I get a

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: #[mule:context.homeDir]\conf\jdbc.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Even if I create a seperate property in the mule configuration, `${homeDir}` which has a value of `#[mule:context.homeDir]` it gives me the same error, except with `${homeDir}` as being unable to resolve.

I've turned logging up and can see it wiring up the property `${homeDir}`, but it seems the the property-placeholder does not want to resolve it. I've tried both  and using a raw bean of the class of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:#[mule:context.homeDir]/conf/jdbc.properties</value>
            <value>file:#[mule:context.homeDir]/conf/standalone-ehcache.conf</value>
            <value>classpath:gateway.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${MULE_HOME}/conf is on Mule's classpath so the following should work:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        <value>classpath:standalone-ehcache.conf</value>
        <value>classpath:gateway.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This works... I couldn't find any documentation for this, but you are right in that this works. Thank you very much.